# How to maintain session of logged user using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, jax-rs, session-cookies

I am creating a webapp using JAX-RS on my backend and jquery on the frontend. I have implemented user login with *@Context HttpRequest* which handles cookies. What I want to know is if there is something like rootscope(from AngularJS) in jquery, where I can easily access info about the logged user, or do I have to, for every new page load, get the logged user from my server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The frontend has no clue about the session in the backend unless the server gives that data to the frontend. I have no clue about jax-rs so no clue how you can easily give that info.

Comment: rootscope is something which will be refreshed once you reload the page.It is just a plane object in angular js , which will be empty once the angular script are executed again .

Comment: So basically I have to send data about the session every time the page is refreshed?

Comment: This is what you get with a SPA; the appearance of state between "pages". I a non-SPA, where pages are real separate pages, you have to live with the face the HTTP is stateless. You need to design your own way to handle the maintenance of  state. Whether you use cookies, headers, or whatever, you need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.